# "Another user changed the record" error not raised after conversion from BDE to FireDAC

Tags: delphi, firedac, bde

I'm working on an application that we recently converted from BDE to FireDAC. I'm having a problem where the "Another user changed the record" mechanism is not working. If we ran two instances of the app against the same database, browsed to a given row in both, updated the row on one instance, and then in the other attempted to change the same field to a different value, we would always get the "Another user changed the record" error. After converting to FireDAC, the update on the second instance just overwrites the first user's change. I'm using a TFDQuery with an associated TFDUpdateSQL for its UpdateObject.  I've tried changing UpdateMode to upWhereAll, but it doesn't change the behavior. What do we need to do differently in FireDAC for this to work?

Using an UpdateObject was needed with the BDE to make the TQuery "live" when the SQL had joins to other tables, etc. We were trying to do the conversion with as little change as possible to avoid introducing any new bugs. But now I'm wondering if I should just eliminate the UpdateObject and let FireDAC do its magic under the hood to make the query editable.

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: In both the BDE and FireDAC, the SQL sent to the server appears to be exactly what is in the UpdateSQL property of the UpdateSQL component. The WHERE clause only has the PK seqno. I like to know how the BDE detects the "another user changed the record". It must be doing another SELECT to check for data changes. FireDAC doesn't seem to do this.

Comment: I'm trying eliminating the UpdateObject and using upWhereChange instead. This seems to be basically working.  It needed for me to populate UpdateOptions.KeyFields with the name of the primary key field.  I was kind of hoping this would happen automatically since I have metadata enabled.

Comment: I tried upWhereAll with FireDAC generating the update SQL but this did not work. It was including in the WHERE clause all the columns that are in the SELECT of the query that are from tables that are being joined to.

Comment: BDE... Haven't seen that in nearly 2 decades! Last I knew, it simply didn't work properly ever since Windows Vista and the new level of Windows security... has this really been working this whole time?

Comment: The BDE still works amazingly well after all these years. Our main product, which is currently still on the BDE, is being used daily by hundreds of users.  The only really serious problem we had was the infamous "4GB boundary" problem. Fortunately someone wrote a work-around, which was a life-saver at the time.